# PreparedStatement on Java and probability to set parameters

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

There is a good way to use a prepared statement in java where there is the possibility to have  a probability that some parameter can be or not be set?

Let's assume I have a complete query like this one:

`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1='....' AND Field2='....' AND Field3='....'`

Then in my program I would like to do something like that (I know it's not possible the way I write)

```
// part of code where I have 3 variable set by some logic and the query itself
//.........

String Query = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1=? ";
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement();          
s.setString(1, Field1Var);

if (Field2Var != Value)
{
    Query += " AND Field2=? ";
    s.setString(2, Field2Var);
}

if (Field3Var != Value3)
{
    Query += " AND Field3=? ";
    s.setString(3, Field3Var);
}
s = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

How can I achieve it without write many different queries?

Comment: you might create a Stored Procedure and execute the procedure with your parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE 1=1";

if (Field1Var != Value1) {
    query += " AND Field1 = ? ";
}

if (Field2Var != Value2) {
    query += " AND Field2 = ? ";
}

if (Field3Var != Value3) {
    query += " AND Field3 = ? ";
}

PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(query); 

int i = 0;

if (Field1Var != Value1) {
    s.setString(++i, Field1Var);
}

if (Field2Var != Value2) {
    s.setString(++i, Field2Var);
}

if (Field3Var != Value3) {
    s.setString(++i, Field3Var);
}
```

1. Use an additional condition 1=1.
2. Use a counter variable.

Or you can write a "NamedPreparedStatement" like I did. (https://gist.github.com/1978317)

Comment: I don't like your answer because it do not reply to my problem and second but not less important you cannot set the variable before preparing the statement... so the setString method return an error because there is no ? and also you cannot call the prepareStatement method without parameters...

Comment: I'm sorry, now it should work. But I think I still don't get your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The whole point of a prepared statement is that it is "prepared" - which means it is parsed (either by the driver, or by the server) and all you do with each run is supply the parameters.

The code you are trying to write is also going to be a nightmare for anyone else to follow. It would be much cleaner if you just sucked it up and wrote the queries. (Or used an ORM tool.)

Comment: yeah I know, but if my query can or cannot have some condition based on some precalc, how can I safe escape the input? I used preparedstatement for exactly this purpose...

Comment: Prepared statements (or, more specifically, the parameter substitution using '?', which you may be able to get from other JDBC classes - I can't remember) is exactly the right way to avoid SQL injection attacks. But (as I commented on the other answer which simply changed your if statements into a loop) all you're doing is setting parameters on a prepared statement and then throwing it away and creating a new one. The API of prepared statement will (rightly) not let you do what you want to do.

Comment: @dty - Do you have a link for this that helps explain this further?

Comment: Could Marcx accomplish something by using multiple PreparedStatements? Assuming it's known which fields are likely to be missing? Anyway, I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use "more object oriented approach" using Hibernate [Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)  that allows you to create queries dynamically ( typical use is search query with many parameters), but i dont know what technology stack you use.