# Updating image saved in mysql blob format

Tags: java, mysql, image, blob

In my programs the user can save an image in mysql via java program.And it will be displayed in a Jlabel. The image inserting part works fine.The image gets inserted and is displayed properly.But when the user try to update it the image is not updated properly.After the update, when I go and check in Mysql, the image is not there. Some garbage value is there. Can anyone help me ?

```
//Method to get the image from the file chooser
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
    jTextField1.setText(filename);

    try {
        File image = new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];

        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
        menu_image_new = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
} 

// Save button click event where the update query run
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        Connection con = DB_Con.getConnection();
        String sql = "update menu set Menu_Image='" + menu_image_new + "' where Menu_Code='" + FoodMenu_FOA.clicked + "'";
        PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image Updated Successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
} 

//Method to display image in Jlabel
public void set_Icon_menu() {
    try {
        int row = menu_table.getSelectedRow();
        Connection con = DB_Con.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs;
        String menu_id = menu_table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
        String sql = "select Menu_Image from menu where Menu_Code='" + menu_id + "'";
        PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            byte[] imagedata = rs.getBytes("Menu_Image");
            format = new ImageIcon(imagedata);
            menu_label.setIcon(format);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to clear the column before writing to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in your Java library, but you should use SQL queries with parameters (probably setBinaryStream or setBlob) instead of concating a SQL string. That might solve your problem...

Found this that might help you :

[PreparedStatement on Java and probability to set parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558952/preparedstatement-on-java-and-probability-to-set-parameters)

http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/MySQL-PreparedStatement-Parameters.html

and this:

http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/jdbc-prepared-statements.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.preparestatement("update menu set Menu_Image= ? where Menu_Code= ?");
stmt.setString(1, menu_image_new);
stmt.setBlob(2, FoodMenu_FOA.clicked);
```

This will create a prepared statement, note entirely sure if it will solve your problem though

Comment: Well, thats exactly the same as I wrote.... @Ashan: Maybe mark my answer as correct :) ?

Comment: yes very sorry I forgot to mark it as correct...its done ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , You need first of all clear blob format in column.
by setting Menu_Image to null

```
// Save button click event where the update query run

     private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   PreparedStatement st;
 try {
    Connection con = DB_Con.getConnection();
 String sql = "update menu set Menu_Image= null where Menu_Code='" + 
   FoodMenu_FOA.clicked + "'";
    st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
    st.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   } 

 // As your are using prepare statement set 

    try {
      Connection con = DB_Con.getConnection();
        String sql = "update menu set Menu_Image= ? where Menu_Code='" + 
      FoodMenu_FOA.clicked + "'";
        st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
      st.executeUpdate();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image Updated Successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
try {
    String update = "update menu set IMAGE=? where Menu_Code='" + 
        edit_idnumber.getText() + "'";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(update);
    pst.setBytes(1, menu_image_new);
    pst.execute();  
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```